# From timeSpan class of SPLUS to POSIXlt class of R

Tags: r, lubridate, s-plus

I am trying to convert `SPLUS` data with `timeSpan` class to `R` data with `POSIXlt` class. I looked into `lubridate` package, but could not find a way to do it. `R` is unable to detect `timeSpan` class, so it spits error when I tried to create a variable with the data.

The `lubridate` package help file `?'lubridate-package'` says that

> Lubridate distinguishes between moments in time (known as instants)
>   and spans of time (known as time spans, see Timespan-class). Time
>   spans are further separated into Duration-class, Period-class and
>   Interval-class objects.

Also I looked for help from this [article](http://vita.had.co.nz/papers/lubridate.pdf) on `lubridate` written by the package developer, but could not find a way to solve it. Is it  possible to convert the `timeSpan` class of `SPLUS` to `posixlt` class in `R`?

**SPLUS Data:**

```
"span" = new("timeSpan", .Data = list(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 7,
    7, 30, 30, 91, 91, 365, 1826, 9131, 36525),
    c(1, 1, 2, 5, 10, 25, 50, 100, 250, 500, 1000, 5000, 15000, 60000, 60000, 
    300000, 300000, 900000, 900000, 3600000, 10800000, 10800000, 21600000,
    0, 0, 0, 37800000, 37800000, 27000000, 27000000, 21600000, 21600000,
    21600000, 0)),
   .Data.names = c("julian.day", "milliseconds"),
   .Data.classes = new("CLASS",c("integer", "integer")),
   format = "%dd %Hh %Mm %Ss %NMS")
```

**Appearance of data after evaluation on SPLUS workbench:**

```
span
 [1] 0d 0h 0m 0s 1MS     0d 0h 0m 0s 1MS     0d 0h 0m 0s 2MS    
 [4] 0d 0h 0m 0s 5MS     0d 0h 0m 0s 10MS    0d 0h 0m 0s 25MS   
 [7] 0d 0h 0m 0s 50MS    0d 0h 0m 0s 100MS   0d 0h 0m 0s 250MS  
[10] 0d 0h 0m 0s 500MS   0d 0h 0m 1s 0MS     0d 0h 0m 5s 0MS    
[13] 0d 0h 0m 15s 0MS    0d 0h 1m 0s 0MS     0d 0h 1m 0s 0MS    
[16] 0d 0h 5m 0s 0MS     0d 0h 5m 0s 0MS     0d 0h 15m 0s 0MS   
[19] 0d 0h 15m 0s 0MS    0d 1h 0m 0s 0MS     0d 3h 0m 0s 0MS    
[22] 0d 3h 0m 0s 0MS     0d 6h 0m 0s 0MS     1d 0h 0m 0s 0MS    
[25] 7d 0h 0m 0s 0MS     7d 0h 0m 0s 0MS     30d 10h 30m 0s 0MS 
[28] 30d 10h 30m 0s 0MS  91d 7h 30m 0s 0MS   91d 7h 30m 0s 0MS  
[31] 365d 6h 0m 0s 0MS   1826d 6h 0m 0s 0MS  9131d 6h 0m 0s 0MS 
[34] 36525d 0h 0m 0s 0MS
```

**Error on R console:**

```
Error in getClass(Class, where = topenv(parent.frame())) : 
  “timeSpan” is not a defined class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking the core `list` `.Data` object out of the S object, you can then manipulate it into an R `difftime`, which can then be added/subtracted from a `POSIXct/lt` or `Date` object:

```
out <- Reduce(`+`,
         Map(as.difftime, Map(`/`, x, c(1,1000)), units=list("days","secs"))
       )
units(out) <- "days"

round(out,4)
#Time differences in days
# [1]     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000
# [7]     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000     0.0001
#[13]     0.0002     0.0007     0.0007     0.0035     0.0035     0.0104
#[19]     0.0104     0.0417     0.1250     0.1250     0.2500     1.0000
#[25]     7.0000     7.0000    30.4375    30.4375    91.3125    91.3125
#[31]   365.2500  1826.2500  9131.2500 36525.0000
```

Where `x` was:

```
x <- list(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 7, 7, 30, 30, 91, 91, 365, 1826, 9131, 36525
), c(1, 1, 2, 5, 10, 25, 50, 100, 250, 500, 1000, 5000, 15000, 
60000, 60000, 3e+05, 3e+05, 9e+05, 9e+05, 3600000, 10800000, 
10800000, 21600000, 0, 0, 0, 37800000, 37800000, 2.7e+07, 2.7e+07, 
21600000, 21600000, 21600000, 0))
```